# sniffing vmnet8 on VMware fusion and OSX 10.6

Tags: vmware-fusion, osx-snow-leopard

I'm currently using VMWare Fusion on Mac OSX and I have a VM running. In order to sniff out the network traffic I ran the following as root :-

`$ /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet-sniffer vmnet8 -w login.pcap -e`

However, a file named login.pcap is not created - Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I've tagged this as "vmware-workstation" as I could not find appropriate tags. I would love to have used "vmnet8", "vmware-fusion".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `vmnet-sniffer` but have you tried using redirection instead of `-w` option:

`$ /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet-sniffer -e vmnet8 > login.pcap`

Comment: Hmm, yeah but the resulting output is not viewable using wireshark - basically the output of "-e"(headers alone) is written out into the file...